# more than (comparative forms)

Tags: comparative-constructions

***Does the following make sense?***

> "Nowadays, there are many more electronic pieces of equipment and
>   devices than there used to be."
>
> "I like the museum. It was more interesting than I expected to be.
>
> "I like the museum. It was more interesting than I expected it to be.
>
> "The more you are tired, the more mistakes you might make".

Comment: Note that *pieces of electronic equipment* is far more idiomatic than *electronic pieces of equipment*, and your final example would usually be phrased as *The more tired you are...* You can't omit the pronoun ***it*** in your second example, but there's nothing wrong with the way you've used ***more + than*** in any of them.

Comment: "The {more people} are tired" vs "the {more tired} people are" is a slight difference ... with "you" the difference doesn't make sense, though. You seem to think "the {more {people are tired}}", which is kind of OK because this construction with "the <argument>, the <argument>" strikes me as colloquial, anyway, because there is no literal connective. But it's uncommon, indeed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would generally agree but if the point is to emphasize that the equipment is electronic, then this order is actually better.  *There are more **electronic** pieces [rather than mechanical] of equipment*. That's how I interpret that first one.

Comment: I'm sorry, Mickey Mouse but this looks like you're asking us to proofread these sentences for you - as such, it is at risk of being closed. I know that you have a specific thing you're focusing on (comparative forms) but we need more information, otherwise you're just asking us to tell you if they're correct or not.